# how to mark latitude and longitude on google map from an online json

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I want to read latitude and longitude from json(online), the json file looks like this.**The latitude is name and longitude is country.**

```
[
  {
    "name": "13.0714562",
    "country": "77.55946348",
    "twitter": "Current Location"
  },
  {
    "name": "13.0714562",
    "country": "77.55946348",
    "twitter": "Current Location"
  },
  {
    "name": "13.0714562",
    "country": "77.55946348",
    "twitter": "Current Location"
  },

  ...................

]
```

I want to plot the latitude and longitude on the google map in android by the above json.

The url for json is:- http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet

I am trying to use asynctask to download the json. Below is my android code.

```
public class Maps extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url = "http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet";
    private static final String latitude = "name";
    private static final String longitude = "country";
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    float lat, lon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);
        new GetMap().execute();
    }

    private class GetMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Maps.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = c.getString(latitude);
                        String time = c.getString(longitude);
                        double LAT = Double.parseDouble(name);
                        double LON = Double.parseDouble(time);
                        final LatLng Marker = new LatLng(LAT, LON);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Marker, 15));
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Marker).title("Revamp 15,click on the arrow below for directions"));
                }

                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Marker).title("Revamp 15,click on the arrow below for directions"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error in **onPostExecute** part of asynctask that  **Marker cannot be resolved to a variable.** So I tried to intialize marker by null. If I do that the json does not get loaded in to the Marker variable.

How can I load the json in Marker Variable?

Comment: You declare a variable called TP twice, can it be the source of your problem?

Comment: Include the logcat error and the imports for the Maps class please

Comment: @TimCastelijns there is no error if i intialize maker by null value, if i do not initialize by null, then android throws me an error that it is not intialized

Comment: Declare LatLng Marker global out side doInBackground and try initialize in doInBackground() then try to use in onPostExecute.

Comment: Google Maps is probably not ready yet when you've received your JSON data. Initialize Google Maps in your activity's onCreate and implement  the `onMapReady` callback and execute your `GetMap` AsyncTask there.

Comment: @HareshChhelana i tried declaring LatLng outside do in background by some dummy values, it shows only the dummy value, not the json value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "Marker cannot be resolved to a variable".
Basically, in onPostExecute you are sending Marker which is not variable. It's a class.

I'm not sure if you can even compile this code? You get compilation error or what?

```
final LatLng Marker = new LatLng(LAT, LON);
```

Instead of "Marker" try naming it "marker". And do it as a global variable. Then in post execute use it again as "marker".

Don't ever use class names as variable name. From [naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java):

> Local variables, instance variables, and class variables are also written in lowerCamelCase

Also, instead of using global variable, you could just send it as a result in your async task. Something like this

```
private class GetMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, LatLng>{

    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        // code...
        return new LatLng(LAT, LON);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LatLng markerLatLng) {
        // code
        Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerLatLng).title("Revamp 15,click on the arrow below for directions"));
        // code
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Maybe try with something like this? This will only work if you did setup the google maps correctly, and everything else is working fine (you could check the comments on your post).

```
public class GetMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<LatLng>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Maps.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<LatLng> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                List<LatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString(latitude);
                    String time = c.getString(longitude);
                    double LAT = Double.parseDouble(name);
                    double LON = Double.parseDouble(time);
                    latLngList.add(new LatLng(LAT, LON));
                }
                return latLngList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<LatLng> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        if (result == null){
            // Error occured, handle it as you wish (log, toast, dialog)
            return;
        }else if(result.size() == 0){
            // There was no any result, handle this as you wish (log, toast, dialog)
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                //there is no point of moving camera from one marker to another, so we will just move to first one
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(result.get(0), 15));
            }
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            for(LatLng latLng : result)
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Revamp 15,click on the arrow below for directions"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not use the Google Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

You'll then have to setup the map, call the service for your information from the server and set the marker afterwards.

cheers